# convert pdf to txt file where bold text placement is changed position

Tags: pdf

given this pdf [image]

is there a way to process it to a txt file with the following specfications:

1. the bold answer to print as the 3rd one
2. to remove empty line between question 1 and 2.

bold answer would have different placement every time as there a lot of questions

Comment: im trying to avoid adding this to a DB and marking correct answer there by a certain marker/id

Comment: thx. i could get the same in word. but cannot find a way to process this with word documents either